# swift NSMutableDictionary error on linux

Tags: ios, linux, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I tried to run the following swift code on ubuntu-16.04,under swift-3.0.1-release:

```
import Foundation

let a = NSMutableDictionary()
a.setObject("value",forKey:"key" as NScopying)
```

Then it gave me an compile error:

```
 error: repl.swift:4:30: error: cannot convert value of type 'NSCopying' to    
 expected argument type 'AnyHashable'
 a.setObject("a",forKey:"xxx" as! NSCopying)
                   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       as! AnyHashable
```

But this code runs well on MacOS

What should i do?

Comment: Do you need the "as" at all? Apart from that, seems to be a difference between NSMutableDictionary implementations.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the string key to NSCopying in the first place?!

Comment: This is the requirement of this method.By the way,the function *setValue* calls for String as  key.

Comment: I have resolved this with replace *NSCopying* with *NSString*.Thanks for your help.